# Square Root Algebraic Manipulation

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

I'd appreciate some help in understanding the steps taken in simplifying the numerator as was done in the following integral:
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^4 + x^{-4} + 2}}{x^3} \space dx = \int \frac{{x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}}}{x^3} \space dx $$ I've tried all the manipulations I could think of but can't reach this simpler form.

Comment: It is far easier to first notice that $(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})^2 = x^4 + x^{-4}+2$ and work backwards from there.  If you were tasked with finding $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$ out of thin air, this just comes with practice and spotting patterns, in particular noticing the coefficients $\color{red}{1}x^4+\color{red}{2}+\color{red}{1}x^{-4}$ follows the nice pattern of $1,2,1$ which you see commonly when doing $(a+b)^2 = 1a^2+2ab+1b^2$ and spotting it from there.

Comment: You spent all the words in a comment. Why? This is a full answer. @JMoravitz

Comment: What if you hade $x^8+2x^4+1$ ? Make the connection.

Comment: @JMoravitz Your comment so far has been the most helpful. What I mean is, it is of course easy verify that $ (x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})^2 = x^4 + x^{-4}+2$ (Which the first answers explain), but I was more interested in knowing if there were some purely algebraic steps that I was missing, besides pattern spotting, that can be replicated in going from $x^4 + x^{-4}+2$ to $ (x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})^2$. Too bad I can't accept a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^2=x^4+2x^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+\frac{1}{x^4}=x^4+x^{-4}+2$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$x^4+{1\over x^4}+2 = (x^2+{1\over x^2})^2$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ (x+1/x)^2= x^2+1/x^2 +2 $$

So

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1/x^{2} + 2}}{x^p} \space dx = \int \frac{(x  + \frac{1}{x})} {x^p} \space dx $$

Now consider power $4$ instead of $2$ in the numerator of the integrand, $p=3$.